# use bash script to pass arguments to a python script

Tags: python, bash, for-loop

I have a very basic problem, but my knowledge about python is very limited. I have a python script that takes several arguments in order to run (https://github.com/raphael-group/hotnet2/blob/master/bin/createPPRMat.py).

I would like to use a file with some filenames (one per line) as the first argument to be passed to the python script.

My first try to do it was creating a bash script (`mat.sh`) like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for net in $(cat /home/hotnet2-1.0.0/iref/iref.list);
do
export
python createPPRMat.py -e `$net` -i /home/jfertaj/hotnet2-1.0.0/iref/iref_index_genes -o /home/jfertaj/Broad_Stay/hotnet2-1.0.0/iref_influence_matrices
done
```

However I got an error, the python script seems to not parse the `$net` variable:

```
createPPRMat_1.py: error: argument -e/--edgelist_file: expected one argument
mat.sh: line 6: /home/jfertaj/Broad_Stay/hotnet2-1.0.0/iref/iref_edgelist_139: No such file or directory
```

When I double quote the variable `net` in the bash script (`"$net"`) the error I got is different, pointing out that something is wrong with the filename

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jfertaj/Broad_Stay/hotnet2-1.0.0/bin/createPPRMat_1.py", line 96, in <module>
run(get_parser().parse_args(sys.argv[1:]))
File "/home/hotnet2-1.0.0/bin/createPPRMat_1.py", line 38, in run
edges = [map(int, l.rstrip().split()[:2]) for l in open(args.edgelist_file)]
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\x1b[01;00m/home/hotnet2-1.0.0/iref/iref_edgelist_164\x1b[0m'
```

The content of `iref.list` looks like this:

```
/home/hotnet2-1.0.0/iref/iref_edgelist_1
/home/hotnet2-1.0.0/iref/iref_edgelist_10
/home/hotnet2-1.0.0/iref/iref_edgelist_100
```

And the `iref.list` file was created using `cat -1 ... < iref.list`

Any help would be very appreciated

Thanks

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: `'\x1b[01;00m/home/hotnet2-1.0.0/iref/iref_edgelist_164\x1b[0m'` this in the output looks like the file has color control codes in it. That's not a text file. You'll need to get a clean text file or strip those out before this will work.

Comment: Oks, I understand the color control codes but why when I use `$net` the error I got is different? Well, maybe it is a really silly question...

Comment: The backticks run their contents as a command. So `\`$net\`` takes the value of the `$net` variable and tries to run it as a shell command and replaces the backtick string with the output of the command. That's why you get the "no such file or directory" error there and why the `-e` argument doesn't have an argument (the backtick string evaluates to the empty string).

Comment: Thanks @EtanReisner for the help and for the information, removing the control codes did the trick. If you post the comments are an answer I would be more than happy to give you the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python traceback shows you the problem (as you noticed).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jfertaj/Broad_Stay/hotnet2-1.0.0/bin/createPPRMat_1.py", line 96, in <module>
run(get_parser().parse_args(sys.argv[1:]))
File "/home/hotnet2-1.0.0/bin/createPPRMat_1.py", line 38, in run
edges = [map(int, l.rstrip().split()[:2]) for l in open(args.edgelist_file)]
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\x1b[01;00m/home/hotnet2-1.0.0/iref/iref_edgelist_164\x1b[0m'
```

The file is not a text file. It is a binary file. It contains file names and shell color codes. You need to remove (or filter out) those color codes before you can use the filenames verbatim (alternatively get a clean copy of the file and fix whatever process spits out color codes to files to stop doing that).

The different error (missing argument) you get when you use the backticks is because  the backticks run their contents as a command. So `` `$net` `` takes the value of the `$net` variable and tries to run it as a shell command and then replaces the entire backtick quoted string with the output of that command.

That's why you get the "no such file or directory" error there (because the filename, with codes, is not valid) and, subsequently, why the `-e` flag doesn't have an argument (the backtick string evaluated to the empty string so you end up with `-e -i` and no argument to `-e`).